# Quadratic Equation $9x^2-\text{ln} c = bx$

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

How to determine the roots ofthe quadratic equation $9x^2 -\text{ln} c= bx$, where $1<c<3$,

$(1)$ real and distinct roots

$(2)$ real and equal roots

$(3)$ no real roots.

Comment: The discriminant is $b^2+36\ln c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$ has real and distinct real roots if and only if

$$B^2-4AC>0$$

therefore for $9x^2 -\ln c= bx \iff 9x^2 -bx -\ln c= 0$ we need

$$b^2+36\ln c>0$$

Comment: Got it.  Because $b^2$ will always be positive and 36 ln $c$ will either be zero or positive.

Comment: @puahkh Yes exactly since $c>1$ then $\ln c>0$ therefore we always have $2$ distinct real roots. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

The discriminant is $b^2+36\ln{c}$. Note that since $c\in(1,3)$, $\ln c$ starts from (not including) $0$ and goes upto a little over 1 (and $\ln$ is strictly increasing). This means the discriminant is surely positive ($b^2$ of course is always positive) and so the roots are real. For the roots to be equal, $b^2+36\ln c = 0$ but this is impossible since both $b^2$ and $36\ln c$ are strictly positive.

$$\boxed{\text{The roots are real and distinct. }}$$

Comment: Thanks for the highlighting that as long as $c$ is above 1, ln $c$ will always be positive.